# Listen to local radio stations?

Tags: wireless, internet-radio

Helloo! Sorry for the noobish question.

Is it possible to listen to local FM/AM radio using a wifi chip built inside a computer?

Or do I need an antena?
What software is best suited for this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mention your OS and its version, the desktop environment. People who can help will find that information useful.

Comment: Only if you have some fancy tranverter to get the signals on 2.4 or 5 Ghz

Comment: @DKBose im using ubuntu 18.04 with the gnome desktop.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The 'radio' in your PC is digital only, and designed to send and receive WiFi signals only, not any Digital Audio modulated signal use by commercial radio broadcasters. Even if you had a 'transverter' (frequency converter) as mentioned in a comment above, you could not do anything with what you received.

HOWEVER

You *can* connect through a web browser or audio streaming app to a website which '[streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media)' (digitally relays) the audio of radio stations to listen to in parallel with what the station also happens to be transmitting (e.g., [WBGO Newark](https://www.wbgo.org/contact-us#stream/0), [CBC Radio One Toronto](https://www.cbc.ca/listen/live-radio?radio_one=ottawa&cbc_music=toronto), and [RTE Radio 1](https://ieradio.org/rte-radio-1/) from Dublin).  Some apps will [record the stream for later playback](https://itsfoss.com/record-streaming-audio/).

Many [internet radio stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_radio_stations) don't even broadcast over the air, and only send their signal out via the internet.

There are multiple providers of streaming services to such broadcasters, i.e., [ICEcast](http://dir.xiph.org/) and [SHOUTcast](https://directory.shoutcast.com/); the latter lists tens of thousands of 'stations' cross-referenced by genre, bandwidth used and encoding type (and therefore fidelity), and popularity.

Comment: thanks! but isnt there a way to connect some kind of antenna to my computer? theres radio stations in my area which arent retransmitted over internet. in fact, i want to become a radio retransmitter haha. any tips?

Comment: "isnt there a way to connect some kind of antenna to my computer?" Not unless you purchase a radio receiver which interfaces to the PC. Discussion of such devices is handled in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further WHY it is not practical:

Radio receivers/transmitters built into computer hardware or accessories, if they are not dedicated SDR (software defined radio) type devices (which are much more expensive than eg a wifi or bluetooth card, so unless you bought one on purpose, you don't have one), are purpose designed and hard-wired for a certain frequency band and modulation type.

Frequency bands and modulation types of broadcast radio and TV services, digital or analog, are completely different from that used for wifi networking, bluetooth, or mobile data. So whatever you do in software will not enable this kind of usage.

For completeness, there are unintentional exceptions to the rule, eg incidental broadcast radio *transmissions* using incidental properties of some other output signal (eg TEMPEST incidents, or some hacks that basically create transmissions by using interference in a clever way), but such are experimental in nature and won't get you closer to receiving broadcast signals at acceptable quality.